# Trying to create a login on my site using soundcloud

Tags: authentication, soundcloud

Can someone explain to me how i can have people register to my site by loggin in with soundcloud?

The same thing that facebook has but i want it for soundcloud so i can verify they are who they say they are. Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out SoundCloud's OAuth2 process?

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/authentication#authorization-code-flow

Once your SoundCloud App is setup you can easily trigger the process from JavaScript 
( http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/javascript-sdk#authentication ), then in your custom redirect_uri callback exchange the OAuth token for a SoundCloud access token.

Retrieving the access token proves that the user is logged into SoundCloud and "are who they say they are." (Persist that access token against the user account your server if you require subsequent authenticated SoundCloud API access on behalf of that user.)

Comment: Yup, this is correct. You can do it with the JavaScript SDK, or any of the other SDKs if you're writing a webapp in Ruby, Python, PHP, etc. SoundCloud also provides images you can use to let your users know they can log in with soundcloud: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/authentication#connect-button-images